# Get seccond Largest Number in a key value pair array with specific distance

Tags: c++, c, arduino, pseudocode

- Im working on a project that maps points of height on the Neck.
- Using an Arduino and a Hall Sensor, I map points of resistance in diferent locations.
- im mapping in a HashMap my points (points[ stepper_motor_location][resistance])
- I need to find the middle point (Cricothyriod ligament )
- I know how to get the upper point ( thyroid cartilage ) by getting the max resistance from all locations.
- but i don't know how to get the bottom point ( Cricoid Cartilage ) which is the seccond highest peak but with a considerable distance from the first highest peak.

### So, the question is :

How do you get the 2nd Highest resistance in points[location][resistance] with a difference of at least 2-10 in location from the Highest resistance?

C, C++, Arduino, or pseudo-code, I sincerely don't mind.

---

Here's my code:

```
/* ###### VARIABLE ######## */
 /*  */
found bool = false; /* while our point is not found, FOUND IS FALSE */
resistance int []; /* resistance vector */
location int []; /* Motor location vector */
current_location int = 0; /* 0 which means the top part of the motor container */
current_resistance int; /* the resistance which the Hall Sensor registers at that moment */
points HashMap; /* HashMap with location as key and resistance at its location as value */
min_distance int = 50; /* value for the minimum distante between the highest point and the second highest point (Variable to be modified as we test more) */

/* ######## FUNCTIONS ######### */
 /*  */
move_check()
{
    location.push(current_location);
    current_resistance = GET_CURRENT_RESISTANCE;
    resistance.push(current_resistance);
    MOVE_MOTOR++;
    location++;
}

map_points()
{
    for(;location <= MAX_DISTANCE;) /* WE SET THE MAX_DISTANCE TO WHAT WE MEASURED BEFORE AS MAX DISTANCE */
    {
        move_check();
        RED_LED = 1;
        RED_LED = 0; /* TO SEE THAT IS MAPPING POINTS */
        }
    }
    CreateHashMap (points, location, resistance, MAX_DISTANCE); /* (VARIABLE_NAME , int, int, NUMBER_OF_ITEMS) */
}

get_top() /* gets the thryoid Cartilage location */
{
    maximum int = 0;
    max_location int = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i<= location.length(); i++)
    {
        if(maximum > max(points[i], maximum))
        {
            maximum = max(points[i], maximum);
        }
        else
        {
            maximum = max(points[i], maximum);
            max_location = i;
        }
    }
    return max_location;
}

get_bottom() /* gets the cricoid cartilage location*/
{
    bottom_point int;
    ??????????????????????????????
    return bottom_point;
}

goto_middle_point()
{
    RED_LED = 1;
    while(location != floor((get_top() + get_bottom()) / 2))
    {
        location--;
    }
    RED_LED = 0;
    BEEP_SPEAKER_LONG;
}

wait_button_press()
{
    resistance_now int = GET_CURRENT_RESISTANCE;
    while(resistance_now != GET_CURRENT_RESISTANCE)
    {
        RED_LED = 1;
        RED_LED = 0;
    }
    SLEEP(1000);
    found = true;
}

done(bool found)
{
    if(found)
    {
        while(location)/*  if location is 0 == false (top location) */
        {
            location--;
            MOVE_MOTOR--;
        }
    }
    BEEP_SPEAKER;
    BEEP_SPEAKER; /* beep speaker twice for done */
    RED_LED = 0; /* stops working */
    GREEN_LED = 1; /* signal for ready */
}

int main()
{
    map_points();
    goto_middle_point();
    wait_button_press();
    done();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure a hashmap is the bast container for this job?

Comment: How many points do you have?  Once you find the highest point, you need to filter based on distance and find the next highest point in that subset.  Am i understanding correctly?

Comment: @Beta any other suggestions? i felt like key value pair was a best contender since i need to store the resistance of each location of the stepper motor.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I don't know how many points I have since i need to test the device I build on the 3d printer and see how far the stepper motor can go in its container. I imagine that i have about 300-400 points so the highest point should be at the beginning of the resistance array and the second highest point that I need to find would be the highest peek of the bottom part of the resistance array.

Comment: I'd probably use a map, but I know very little about Arduino and its requirements. Anyway, you can iterate over a hashmap (if the implementation isn't really perverse). A map is a little faster for this job, that's all.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation: `points[location][resistance]`.  Do you mean that `resistance = points[location]` where points is a hashmap having keys as locations and values as resistance measurements?

Comment: @MFisherKDX Yes. exactly.

Comment: @Beta im using Associative Arrays from what I found here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1074030/HashMaps-Associative-Arrays-with-the-Arduino-Progr

Comment: this is basically what i need to find: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricothyrotomy#/media/File:Larynx_external_Cricothyrotomy.gif

Comment: @Beta I don't know much arduino either, My colleague takes what I made in semi C, semi Arduino code  and remakes it to work on the Arduino. so I could give him pseudo-code, but it would be easier for him if I try to write as much Arduino code as I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which implementation of Arduino HashMap you are using, but if it's [this one](https://github.com/ARISGames/arduino/blob/master/libraries/ArduinoPusherClient/HashMap/HashMap.h), this is the best I can come up with given the API.  It is certainly not optimal, and a better data structure would be faster.

Assuming I understand the problem correctly, I would just do a linear search.  You know how to get the highest point.  You know the location of the second highest point must be below the highest. (I'm adding here, you might need to subtract if your coordinate system is different). Assume the minimum difference in positions has to be `min_dist` (some value 2-10).

```
HashMap<int, int, N> points = ...;
int key_low = upper_position + min_dist;
int peak_location = -1;
for(int i=0; i < points.size(); ++i)
{ 
    int location = points.keyAt(i);
    if (location < key_low) continue;
    int resistance = points[location];
    if (peak_location < 0 || resistance > points[peak_location])
    {
        peak_location = location; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. I'l try to translate it in my code. btw this is my code for the moment: https://pastebin.com/gKKvMiTp. Sorry I didn't post it earlier. I highlighted with ?????? where I need to insert your code so I works. It's semi C, and Semi Arduino code, so I hope it's not to confusing.